# Filter condition in WHERE clause in HiveQL query does not work properly

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

When I run the following query through beeline, one of the filter conditions in WHERE clause  (`array_item in (20, 30)`) does not seem to work correctly.

- Hive version: `2.1.1`

```sql
with sample as (
              select 1 as col, array(10)         as array_col
    union all select 2 as col, array(10, 20, 30) as array_col
    union all select 3 as col, array(20, 30)     as array_col
    union all select 4 as col, array(30)         as array_col
)

, targets as (
    select 2 as col_target
)

select
    col
    , array_col
    , array_item
from
    sample
    lateral view explode(array_col) a as array_item
where
    true
    and array_item in (20, 30)
    and sample.col in (select col_target from targets)
```

Although I was expecting the following result to be displayed,

```
col array_col   array_item
2   [10,20,30]  20
2   [10,20,30]  30
```

the actual resuls returned by the query was as follows, showing that the query failed to apply the condition `array_item in (20, 30)`

```
col array_col   array_item
2   [10,20,30]  10
2   [10,20,30]  20
2   [10,20,30]  30
```

For verification, I also ran the following query.
This seemed to be executed correctly and returned the result same as what I expected.

```sql
with sample as (
              select 1 as col, array(10)         as array_col
    union all select 2 as col, array(10, 20, 30) as array_col
    union all select 3 as col, array(20, 30)     as array_col
    union all select 4 as col, array(30)         as array_col
)

, targets as (
    select 2 as col_target
)

select
    col
    , array_col
    , array_item
from
    sample
    lateral view explode(array_col) a as array_item
where
    true
    and array_item in (20, 30)
    and sample.col in (2)  -- changed here: "2" is same as the result of subquery
```

The difference between the first and second query is whether I write the subquery or the result returned by the subquery in the WHERE clause .

So I guess both queries are logically same, but they return different results.

I don't know why the first query does not consider `array_item in (20, 30)`.

Comment: Looks like bug to me. Can you check if changing any of these settings to false help? `hive.auto.convert.join` or `hive.optimize.ppd`

Answer (score 0):

I did some testing in Hive4 Alpha2 using hadoop 3.3.1 and tez 0.10.2

Looks like some bug when hive.optimize.ppd is true for first query.

By setting `hive.optimize.ppd=false` first query also work same as 2nd version.

Comment: Thank you for your comment and answer.  
It sure looks like a bug.  
  
Also in my environment: hive 2.1.1 on cdh 6.3.2, setting `hive.optimize.ppd=false` made the first version return the same result as the second one.

Comment: Unfortunately, however, this setting is unlikely to be applicable in queries with large tables that are actually used in business, rather than the small queries described in the question part, because setting `hive.optimize.ppd=false` would make the query too slow to be practical.

So I guess we'll have to wait for the bug to be worked out, or rewrite the query in a way that doesn't contain subqueries in WHERE clause.